# In Android, how can I tell my app to use a headset that's connected to the USB port on my car dock?

Tags: android, audio, dock, headset

I have a Motorola RAZR and a car dock for it ([this one](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Mobile+Phone+Accessories/Car-Accessories/Car-Mounts/Vehicle-Navigation-Dock-for-DROID-RAZR-US-EN)). That dock has a special USB cable that not only charges the phone, but has a 3.5mm audio plug on it. I can connect a headset to it (instead of using the phone's 3.5mm jack), and the music plays through it. I also checked out the Galaxy Nexus car dock, and it has the same setup.

I also have an app that plays back audio, and it has the ability to toggle the audio output in my app between the internal speaker and the speakerphone. And whenever any headset is pluggedinto the phone's 3.5mm port, the phone automatically routes audio to the headset instead of the internal speaker. But whenever a headset is plugged into the dock, I can't get my phone to detect or use it (`isWiredHeadsetOn()` returns false). The audio still gets routed to the internal speaker, not the headset.

Is there a way to detect that USB-plugged headset, and is there a way to force my app to route audio to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out -- my app was using `AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL` for audio output to support the SCO BT headsets, but for the dock headset to work, the stream has to be `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`. The audio then automatically gets routed to the wired headset plugged into the dock.